# How to prevent TextBlock from getting automatic focus

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I have the following XAML excerpt :

```
      <SplitView Name="Menu" DisplayMode="CompactOverlay" OpenPaneLength="200" CompactPaneLength="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <SplitView.Pane>
                <StackPanel>
                    <AutoSuggestBox Margin="0,20,0,20" Width="170" PlaceholderText="Search" QueryIcon="Find"></AutoSuggestBox>
                    <ListBox>
                        <ListBoxItem Tapped="Projects_Tapped">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <SymbolIcon Symbol="Library" />
                                <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0">Projects</TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ListBoxItem>
                        [....]
                    </ListBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </SplitView.Pane>
        </SplitView>
```

Basically, this splitview is compacted until the user presses a button which then sets the `IsPaneOpen` to true, which in turn shows my application menu.

The problem is, the very first thing i have in the menu is the search box and it seems to be getting focused automatically no matter what i do. The fact that it has focus then brings up the touch keyboard on phones, which is very annoying and hides most of the menu on small phones.

I tried playing with the `TabIndex` property to either give it a huge number or even put a lower index for something else.

I also tried setting the `IsTabStop` to false but that didn't seem to do anything.

Is there a clean way to prevent the box from gaining focus automatically? (Besides disabling / hiding the element and then enabling / showing it again)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

Give `ListBox` a name:

```
<ListBox Name="MyListBox">
```

Then, where you call `IsPaneOpen` to `true`, add the following line:

```
Menu.IsPaneOpen = true;
MyListbox.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
```

This would change the focus to the `ListBox` element and dismiss the keyboard when you open the `SplitView`.

Comment: While this solution did work for me, i preferred Elvis' answer because i feel it's more clean. I was trying to avoid C# code altogether..

Answer (score 0):

It is the TextBox inside the AutoSuggestBox that is retrieving the focus automatically.

To fix the problem, you can edit the template of AutoSuggestBox by:

Click 'Document Outline' tag->choose AutoSuggestBox Element from the Document Tree->right click->Edit Template->Edit a copy.

Then VS will add the Template to your page Resources. Add `IsTabStop="False"` to the TextBox inside the template like below:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="AutoSuggestBox">
     <Grid>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
           ...
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBox" IsTabStop="False" ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="False" DesiredCandidateWindowAlignment="BottomEdge" Header="{TemplateBinding Header}" Margin="0" PlaceholderText="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}" Style="{TemplateBinding TextBoxStyle}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Canvas.ZIndex="0"/>
        <Popup x:Name="SuggestionsPopup">
           ...
        </Popup>
     </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Then, it will stop getting focus automatically.

Comment: Clean and simple detailed explanation, I love it! Thanks

Comment: For someone else having this problem. What ended up working for me was to give a button (or something else you don't mind getting focus) a TabIndex of 2. So that get's focus on startup.

Answer (score -2):

I simple set TabIndex to 999 and this solved my problem:

```
<AutoSuggestBox TabIndex="999" />
```

Before I tried accepted answer, but it causes not to getting focus altogether, i.e. impossible to use textbox at all (can't focus on it, no keyboard pops up, etc).

Comment: Downvoting as not only this is a hack and not a fix, but it also doesn't answer the original question. Yes `IsTabStop` will prevent the element from being focusable (it's kinda explicit in the name) but with your suggestion you are avoiding the problem. Now that I have more XAML knowledge, I believe the best answer is Justin's so I am choosing that one now

Comment: It may be not the exact match with the question, but I get to this page with the similar problem and thank to that page I found the solution. So I think other people may be also interested in. It works for me, and XAML solution is generally more reliable, than trying manually overcome and shift the focus programmatically.